# Can't understand how this jquery plugin works

Tags: jquery, plugins

I was working on a code school course but I'm very confused about how jquery plugins work. Can someone explain the plugin below like I'm 5?

Thanks.

```
$.fn.photofy = function() {

  this.each(function() {
    var tour = $(this);
    var wtf = function(event){

      event.preventDefault();
      tour.addClass("is-showing-photofy");

    };
    tour.on('click.photofy', '.see-photos', wtf);
  });
}
```

Comment: All it really does is add a class whenever someone clicks an element with the class `.see-photos` inside the element the plugin is instantiated on.